# Error in Datasnap query, leaves connection on SQL even if client disconnects

Tags: delphi, datasnap

In Delphi Datasnap server, if some kind of error happens in sql query or stored procedure, the SQL Server keeps connection active even if client disconnects from Datasnap server, until I close the Datasnap server.
It is easy to reproduce, just create Datasnap server from wizard. Put some select query that will certain return error eg. "select bud_beer from users" :)
Create client from wizard also, with TClientDataSet connected to provider which loads beers :)
Now open the Enterprise manager, filter by server and user, and observe the connections.
Open the ClientDataSet, you will get error of course.
You will see the connection in Enterprise manager. Close the client, connection will remain, and will disappear when datasnap server is closed.
If more client are opened, then more connection get stucked in SQL server until datasnap server is closed.

Source from server:

```
unit ServerContainerUnit1;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Datasnap.DSTCPServerTransport,
  Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSCommonServer,
  Datasnap.DSAuth, IPPeerServer;

type
  TServerContainer1 = class(TDataModule)
    DSServer1: TDSServer;
    DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport;
    DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass;
    procedure DSServerClass1GetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
      var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
    procedure DSServer1Connect(DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
    procedure DSServer1Disconnect(DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
  end;

var
  ServerContainer1: TServerContainer1;

implementation

uses Winapi.Windows, ServerMethodsUnit1, Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
begin
  LogInfo('Connected');
end;

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Disconnect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
begin
  LogInfo('Disconnected');
end;

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerClass1GetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := ServerMethodsUnit1.TServerMethods1;
end;

end.
```

and dfm:

```
object ServerContainer1: TServerContainer1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Height = 271
  Width = 415
  object DSServer1: TDSServer
    OnConnect = DSServer1Connect
    OnDisconnect = DSServer1Disconnect
    Left = 96
    Top = 11
  end
  object DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport
    Server = DSServer1
    Filters = <>
    Left = 96
    Top = 73
  end
  object DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass
    OnGetClass = DSServerClass1GetClass
    Server = DSServer1
    Left = 200
    Top = 11
  end
end
```

server methods:

```
unit ServerMethodsUnit1;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSAuth,
  Data.DBXMSSQL, Data.FMTBcd, Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Datasnap.Provider;

type
  TServerMethods1 = class(TDSServerModule)
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    SQLDataSet1: TSQLDataSet;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    procedure DSServerModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DSServerModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

{var
  ServerMethods1: TServerMethods1;}

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}
uses Unit2;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TServerMethods1.DSServerModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LogInfo('Created methods');
end;

procedure TServerMethods1.DSServerModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LogInfo('Destroyed methods');
end;

end.
```

and dfm:

```
object ServerMethods1: TServerMethods1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = DSServerModuleCreate
  OnDestroy = DSServerModuleDestroy
  Height = 445
  Width = 561
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    DriverName = 'MSSQL'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'SchemaOverride=%.dbo'
      'DriverUnit=Data.DBXMSSQL'

        'DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver180.' +
        'bpl'

        'DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borla' +
        'nd.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=18.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicK' +
        'eyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'

        'MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDr' +
        'iver180.bpl'

        'MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFact' +
        'ory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=18.0.0.0,Culture=neutral' +
        ',PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'
      'GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMSSQL'
      'LibraryName=dbxmss.dll'
      'VendorLib=sqlncli10.dll'
      'VendorLibWin64=sqlncli10.dll'
      'HostName=xxxx'
      'Database=xxxx'
      'MaxBlobSize=-1'
      'LocaleCode=0000'
      'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
      'OSAuthentication=False'
      'PrepareSQL=True'
      'User_Name=xxxxx'
      'Password=xxxxx'
      'BlobSize=-1'
      'ErrorResourceFile='
      'OS Authentication=False'
      'Prepare SQL=False')
    Left = 56
    Top = 40
  end
  object SQLDataSet1: TSQLDataSet
    CommandText = 
      'select bud_beer from users'
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <>
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    Left = 56
    Top = 104
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = SQLDataSet1
    Left = 140
    Top = 104
  end
end
```

util

```
unit Unit2;

interface
procedure LogInfo(line: string);

implementation

uses Unit1, System.SysUtils;

procedure LogInfo(line: string);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now)+' '+line);
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

end.
```

and client:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, DBXDataSnap, IPPeerClient,
  Data.DBXCommon, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Data.DB,
  Datasnap.DBClient, Datasnap.DSConnect, Data.SqlExpr;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dspcCommon: TDSProviderConnection;
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses proxy;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Active := true;
end;

end.
```

1. Question is: Why is this happening? How can I avoid-it?

Thank You!

Comment: Enterprise manager is : Microsoft SQL Server Studio

Comment: Keeping database connections open is usually a good thing - it will speed up responses. After a query failed, the next one could work. 
If you need a different management, you have to handle some errors at the Datasnap server level, the client does know almost nothing about the database server behind, and it can be even no database server at all.

Comment: Wow, so you mean the Datasnap server didn't close the connection to the SQL Server instance because one of the queries to it, raised an exception?

Comment: @nolaspeaker , Yes, thats right. If you start client 4 times, you will got 4 errors and 4 connections on SQL Server, even if you close the clients. Connections will remain on server until datasnap server is closed.

Comment: That makes 100% sense. Until your datasnap client disconnects (by closing on the client's TSQLConnection to), the datasnap server is going to keep the TCP/IP connection and it's associated connection to the database open. Why must it do something else (that you didn't ask it to do)? It is your job as a developer to cater for this situation yourself and make decisions about how you want your server/client to work. If you want it to disconnect when an exception is raised at the client, trap it yourself at the the client (try...except...end) and do a TSqlConnection.Close yourself.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Well no! SQL connection remains active, even if client disconnects! I wrote "keeps connection active even if client disconnects from Datasnap server". When I say SQL connection remains active, it means that I can see connection through Activity Monitor from SQL Server Management Studio, even if client, which raised an exception, is DISCONNECTED from datasnap server!

Comment: I was intrigued by your assertion and set up my most-recent Datasnap project to test it. In my test, the database connection ends when the Servermethodsunit is destroyed. I am using D10. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Delphi XE4 Architect...

Comment: I found where the problem is! After testing DataSnap server/client in Delphi XE6, I discovered that DBXMSS.dll library from XE6 is working how it should work. So I now have dbxmss.dll from XE6 with my project, Datasnap server, which is made with XE4! And there is no lost mssql connections on the server!